# How to move documents to another Site collection from Designer workflow

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have 2 different site collection on SharePoint online. Initially file will be uploaded in one site collection after the approval approve the file then I wanted to move that file to another site collection.

Let me know the is this possible & how can we achieve this.

Answer (score 3):

You can use **Content Organizer** feature to route documents to different site collection.

1. Implement a designer workflow to copy the file to Drop off Library after approval.
2. Configure content organiser rule to move the file to target site collection.

Learn more about [Content Organizer](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Configure-the-Content-Organizer-to-route-documents-b0875658-69bc-4f48-addb-e3c5f01f2d9a).

Answer (score 2):

Your only option is to use the REST API. The implementation will be a bit tricky because of the complexity involved.

See this article for a detailed walkthrough

http://johnliu.net/blog/2014/2/19/using-sharepoint-designer-2013-workflow-to-copy-file-via-res.html

The REST URL Format is -

`https://tenant.sharepoint.com/siteurl/_api/web/folders/GetByUrl('SourceDocumentLibrary')/Files/getbyurl('FileToCopy.Extension')/copyTo(strNewUrl='/TargetSiteUrl/DestinationLibrary/FileName.Extension',bOverWrite=true)`

Comment: Thanks Amal for reply.... I am reading the same article which you shared. But in this application doping file to same library with different name. I needed to copy to some other site collection.

Comment: I would suggest you try with the URL format in my updated answer